# SQL query with joining and union clause

Tags: sql

I need a query to join 3 tables and also union with the thrid table. PFA the image. I have put a sample data in 3 tables and results in the o/p table as well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLZHF.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for your response and feedback. Would keep in mind the above things!!

Comment: It would have been great if you would have answered the question as well.

Comment: If you will edit your question to include sample data as DDL+DML and desired results, perhaps I could try to answer it. As it is now, I'm not going to spend even one second answering it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. In the place of null in second union query, depending on the data type, you can use '0' or '0.00'

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT t1.po_id po_id
        ,t1.tmcode tmcode
        ,t1.sp_code
     FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2
        ON t1po.id = t2po.id
    INNER JOIN t3
        ON t2.spid = t3.spid

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NULL
        ,NULL
        ,sp_code
    FROM t3
    )
SELECT po_id
    ,tmcode
    ,Sp_code
FROM cte
```